# python - grouping list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to group every element in the list with all other elements in the list

for ex -

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
```

I try using zip:

```
l2 = list(zip(l1,l1[1:]))
```

but it gives me:

```
l2 = [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]
```

for

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its what that [*itertools.combinations*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is for :

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(l1,2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```